# Cannot find property length of undfined error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following code that when I've **results** Its working ok but if
isnt I got error ,
There is a way in javascript to avoid it in **one line of code** or I must spread it for two lines? if I must how its recomended >

```
   if( oData[aProp[0].split('/')[0]].results.length > 0){

     ....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can do it in one line with:

```
if( oData[aProp[0].split('/')[0]].results
    && oData[aProp[0].split('/')[0]].results.length > 0){
}
```

but this is inefficient because you are doing the split twice, and looks a bit messy.

It is better and easier to read to create a variable first:

```
var oDataEntry = oData[aProp[0].split('/')[0]];
if( oDataEntry.results && oDataEntry.results.length > 0){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var tempArr = null;
var tempAProp = null;
var tempLength = (tempAProp = aProp[0]) && ( tempArr= oData[tempAProp.split('/')[0]]) ?  tempArr.length:0;

if( tempLength > 0){
}
```